# Mysql group by timeinterval and day

Tags: mysql

Whats the best way to group data in time intervals per day
so the intervals would be something like: `0:00 - 7:00 // 7:00 - 19:00 // 19:00 - 0:00`

I also want to have the data by day.
This is how far i got:

```
SELECT bj, name, sum(uptime) as uptime, env, startTimeFrame, endTimeFrame, DATE(startTimeFrame) as s_date, DATE(endTimeFrame) as e_date FROM `uptime_hourly` group by bj, env, s_date
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current query has a number of problems, including that you are selecting non aggregate columns while using `GROUP BY`.  This isn't logically correct most of the time.  In any case, I can offer the following query which uses the time component of the `startTimeFrame` to group your data by the three intervals you described.

```
SELECT t.bj, SUM(t.uptime) AS uptime, t.env, t.s_date,
       CASE WHEN t.h_date < '07:00:00' THEN '0:00 - 7:00'
            WHEN t.h_date >= '07:00:00' AND t.h_date < '19:00:00' THEN '7:00 - 19:00'
            ELSE '19:00 - 0:00' END AS time_interval
FROM
(
    SELECT bj, uptime, env, DATE_FORMAT(DATE(startTimeFrame), '%H:%i:%s') AS h_date,
           DATE_FORMAT(DATE(startTimeFrame), '%Y-%m-%d') AS s_date
    FROM uptime_hourly
) t
GROUP BY t.bj, t.env, t.s_date,
         CASE WHEN t.h_date < '07:00:00' THEN '0:00 - 7:00'
              WHEN t.h_date >= '07:00:00' AND t.h_date < '19:00:00' THEN '7:00 - 19:00'
              ELSE '19:00 - 0:00' END
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it works but there is a small mistake ELSE '19:00 - 0:00' END AS interval should be ELSE '19:00 - 0:00' END AS 'interval' (you forgot the quotes around interval)

Comment: @RobertStevens No, `interval` is a MySQL keyword, and I should have not used it as an alias.  Using `time_interval` _without_ quotes should work just fine (q.v. my updated answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
GROUP BY (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_stamp) + 5) DIV 30
```

should give you sums between hh:mm:05 and hh:mm:35 and between hh:mm:35 and hh:mm+1:05.